# pdo how to check if it is 1st record that retrieve from database?

Tags: php, pdo

```
              $sql3 = "SELECT member FROM levels where upline = ? AND level=1";
              $q3 = $conn->prepare($sql3);
              $q3->execute(array("$level2downlines"));
              while($r3 = $q3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                      $level3downlines = $r3['member'];
                      if (it is 1st record){
                        echo "make orange juice";
                      }else{
                        echo "make all juice";
                      }
              }
```

Let say output are 3 records from database "Zac", "Michelle", Andrew". "Zac" is the 1st record get from database, how to write the "if" statement to check if the records is 1st record or not?

Comment: 1st record based on what? insertion order?

Comment: Base on $level3downlines php variable. Code above using while loop, so $level3downlines variable 1st loop is "Zac", 2nd loop is "Michelle", 3rd loop is "Andrew". 2nd and 3rd loop do the same action, only 1st loop must do other different action, that's why i need if else statement to check if it is 1st loop / 1st result from while loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, if the order of records returned matters, you must explicitly include an `ORDER BY` clause in your query to specify which column to sort results on. Otherwise, the order of rows returned is technically indeterminate.

To operate differently on the first fetched row than on later rows, you may simply call `fetch()` outside the loop first, then loop over the remainder. Each call to `PDOStatement::fetch()` will advance the rowset record pointer, so the `while` loop will only iterate the records after the one already retrieved.

```
// Fetch the first row from the rowset
$r3 = $q3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$level3downlines = $r3['member'];
// Do actions specific to 1st row before the loop
echo "make orange juice";

// Then fetch the remaining rows with a loop
// and perform the their actions in the loop.
// The rowset record pointer has advanced beyond the 1st row
while($r3 = $q3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  $level3downlines = $r3['member'];
  echo "make all juice";
}
```

In practice, I don't often do operations while fetching rows unless the rowset is very large. Instead I would more likely retrieve all rows as an array where I can more easily perform array operations on the set.

```
// Get all rows
$all_rows = $q3->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// Pull the first row off the set
$first_row = array_shift($all_rows);
// do whatever with $first_row

// Loop over the other rows
foreach ($all_rows as $index => $row) {
   // Do whatever with $row
}
```

Instead of using `array_shift()` in that way, when using `$index => $row` in the `foreach` loop, you could also check `$index == 0` to operate on your first row.  You may find this more understandable.

```
foreach ($q3->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $index => $row) {
   // First row
   if ($index == 0) {
     // Do first row actions
   }
   else {
     // Do common actions for remaining rows.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but you want to do a special action for the first row,

```
$sql3 = "SELECT member FROM levels where upline = ? AND level=1";
$q3 = $conn->prepare($sql3);
$q3->execute(array("$level2downlines"));
$first_row = true;
while($r3 = $q3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $level3downlines = $r3['member'];
    if ($first_row){
        echo "make orange juice";
        $first_row = false;
    }else{
        echo "make all juice";
    }
}
```

UPDATE: Michael Berkowski's answer is better and faster.

Comment: you answer is more easy to understand, and very creative. I think your methiod is more optimize the speed right? because only fetch 1 time while Michael's method fetch 2 times.

Comment: I'm not sure actually, but you can do a test and see which one is actually faster.